# TextInputLayout error message keeps showing up even if the set condition result is false

Tags: java, android

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oxK6.jpg)

This is the code is used for my application:

```
if (password.isEmpty() && confirmPassword.isEmpty()) {
            candidatePassword.setError("Field Cannot Be Empty");
            candidateConfirmPassword.setError("Field Cannot Be Empty");
        } else if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            candidatePassword.setError("Passwords Do Not Match");
            candidateConfirmPassword.setError("Passwords Do Not Match");
        } else {
            candidatePassword.setError(null);
            candidateConfirmPassword.setError(null);
        }
```

Actually, I have 2 versions of this. This one is for the "candidates", and the other is for the "voters". This piece of code works with no issues in the "voters" version of this. Can you point out what I am missing, and what need to do? Thank you!

This is the requested XML code for this activity:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/university_of_makati_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:text="Candidacy Registration"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/candidateImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickableText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:text="@string/clickable_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:text="Log-In Details"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clickableText" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidateEmail"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="UMak Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidatePassword"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="25"
            app:counterTextColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateEmail"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Create Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidateConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidatePassword"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:text="Candidate Details"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateConfirmPassword" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidateFullName"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Full Name"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidateYearSection"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateFullName">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Year &amp; Section"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidatePosition"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateYearSection">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Candidacy Position"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidateAchievements"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidatePosition">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Achievements Acquired"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidatePersonalQualities"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateAchievements">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Personal Qualities"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/candidateBackground"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidatePersonalQualities">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Candidacy Background"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/candidateCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Information Provided is Relevant and Legitimate"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateBackground" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/candidateRegistrationButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/candidateCheckBox" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is where I assigned my Strings:

```
private void registerCandidate() {
    try {
        String email = candidateEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String password = candidatePassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword = candidateConfirmPassword.getEditText().toString();
        String fullName = candidateFullName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String yearSection = candidateYearSection.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String position = candidatePosition.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String achievements = candidateAchievements.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String personalQualities = candidatePersonalQualities.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String background = candidateBackground.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: @Hiraeths I have done that too but I still can't seem to remove it

Comment: do you know how to use breakpoints ? if you were to step through your code to debug it, you should have a better understanding of the values and then you can see why your code jumps to the else

Comment: @a_local_nobody i have forgotten how to use breakpoints. can you point me where I can learn to use those?

Comment: Your screenshot does not show any error for the first password field (but it should, right?). 
Check your layout definition and the IDs you use.

Comment: @Antoine both fields should not have any error messages since I programmed these two fields that if password and confirmPassword are equal to each other, error messages should be removed if it present, otherwise, no error message should appear

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But according the Java code you are showing us, you should either have errors on your two password fields (`candidatePassword` + `candidateConfirmPassword`) or no error at all. It is not the case on the screenshot you linked. Maybe you could add the layout xml file, it would be easier to debug.

Comment: @Antoine the screenshot I linked only shows that the error message is still present on the confirm password field despite the 2 fields having the same text. I will add my XML file regarding this activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo in the code where you get the String values.

It should be:

```
String password = candidatePassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
String confirmPassword = candidateConfirmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
```

Comment: I did what you said but still, the error message is present. I can show you the "voter" version of this. On that version, the code works without issues.

Comment: Can you also provide the code where you assign the Strings `password` and `confirmPassword`?

Comment: `errorEnabled` has nothing to do with this. What it does is "reserve" the space for the error to be shown below (if/when it's needed). This avoids the view growing in vertical size (which can upset other views and cause unwanted view effects).

Comment: My bad, I thought it was setting the error flag to be shown.

Comment: @Antoine I have included the code where I assigned the Strings. Please check.

Comment: OH MYY GOOODDDD! I did not notice this. Thank you! @Antoine
Now... How can I mark this question as solved?

Comment: Small typo I think: `candidateConfirmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();`